# get the auto computed margin in firefox with jQuery

Tags: jquery, firefox, cross-browser

With the markup and css below, I tried to get the computed left-margin of shell.

```
 <section class="page-title">
      <div class="shell">
        <h5 class="title">Welcome!</h5>
      </div>
    </section>

.shell {
  zoom: 1;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
}
```

Using

```
parseInt($('.shell').css('marginLeft'))
```

it works in Chrome, Safari, IE9 but surprisingly doesn't work in Firefox. Tried the other approach:

```
($('.shell').outerWidth(true) - $('.shell').outerWidth()) / 2
```

Also works well but Firefox. So I guess firefox doesn't support to obtain the undefined css with jQuery? A straight forward way to work around with it is:

```
($('.page-title').width() - $('.shell').outerWidth()) / 2
```

But I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with Firefox v21

Comment: I have the same problem in Firefox v37.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

When you say it doesn't work, do you receive errors (in the console) or does it return 0? Returning 0 for the auto setting is, apparently, an issue with different browsers.

You could use the lightweight [jSizes](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/) library which returns all metrics in pixels. This will save you having to faff around with outerWidth, etc..

Comment: this lib return 0 when `margin: auto`. Is there a way to get margin in this case?

Comment: jQuery (and probably vanilla JS) also returns 0px for 'auto'. I don't think you could obtain the value `auto` **reliably and consistently** cross-browser. auto means "let the browser decide" and it is this browser-based value that you are reading.

Comment: (What does margin-left etc. return?)