# Different values for jQuery.css('top-margin') with margin:auto based on browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let me try to lay this out, my question is why don't all the browsers treat this the same way.

html

```
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Css

```
body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.container{
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin: auto;
}
.footer{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

jQuery

```
var footertop = (parseFloat($('#container').css('margin-top'))+parseFloat($('#container').css('height')))+'px';
$('#footer').css('top',footertop);
```

I have a container div that is absolutely centered horizontally and vertically.  Then I am attempting to set the 'top' of the footer to be the height of container plus the top margin of container. (So that it ends up right underneath the container).  This method works on some browsers (Chrome,Opera,Safari,IE9+) but doesn't work on others (Firefox,IE8-).

I am assuming IE8 and earlier doesn't support this method, and that's fine, but in Firefox the value of footertop is always equal to $('#container').css('height')

If I do a console.log(parseFloat($('#container').css('margin-top'))) I get a positive integer depending on the height of my browser, but on Firefox it is always 0.

Please advise.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: jquery version: 1.10.2

Comment: similar to this question, but not exactly the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907145/get-the-auto-computed-margin-in-firefox-with-jquery

Comment: can you put the `#footer` div inside container, and then set `bottom` to height of the div? http://jsbin.com/aJEHofu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in firefox the computed value for margin-top, margin-bottom, margin-left and margin-right all end up as 0 and the top,bottom,left and right attributes have the values that you would expect to find in the margins.

here is my jquery that works on all browsers now:

```
if(parseFloat($('#container').css('margin-top')) == 0){
    var footertop = (parseFloat($('#container').css('top'))+parseFloat($('#container').css('height')))+'px'; //firefox fix
}else{
    var footertop = (parseFloat($('#container').css('margin-top'))+parseFloat($('#container').css('height')))+'px';
}
$('#footer').css('top',footertop);
```